# How I can change background image for every controller page in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have created a default.ctp file in layout folder. The header, footer and navigation are same for all the pages but background image are different. All pages are in a separate controller. So I want to use conditional statement in default.ctp file so that I can change background image with respective controller. Is there any way to use conditional statement in default.ctp file in cakephp like that? If so, then please tell me the syntax of conditional statements. If not, then how I can solve my problem? I am very novice in cakephp. So please Help me.

Comment: Oh I got the answer. I just need to use the following syntax in view file: <?php if ($this->params['controller'] == 'your_controller_name'): ?> Call html image file here  <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no. Keep the logic in your controller as far as you can.

first, define default background, which will used when there's no background for controller.
second, set background for every controller you want special background.

very basic example:

app_controller:

```
$this->set('background', '/img/default_background.jpg');
```

controller:

```
$this->set('background', '/img/controller_x_background.jpg');
```

layout:

```
<style type="text/css">
body{
   <?= 'background: url("'.$background.'")'; ?>
}
</style>
```